# Почему в mask не работают id с квадратными скобками?

Tags: javascript

У меня input с `id="xfield[tel]"`.

Если я так подключаю, то перестаёт работать. Как починить?

`input` менять нельзя

```js
/*
    jQuery Masked Input Plugin
    Copyright (c) 2007 - 2015 Josh Bush (digitalbush.com)
    Licensed under the MIT license (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)
    Version: 1.4.1
*/
! function(a) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : a("object" == typeof exports ? require("jquery") : jQuery)
}(function(a) {
  var b, c = navigator.userAgent,
    d = /iphone/i.test(c),
    e = /chrome/i.test(c),
    f = /android/i.test(c);
  a.mask = {
    definitions: {
      9: "[0-9]",
      a: "[A-Za-z]",
      "*": "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    autoclear: !0,
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: "_"
  }, a.fn.extend({
    caret: function(a, b) {
      var c;
      if (0 !== this.length && !this.is(":hidden")) return "number" == typeof a ? (b = "number" == typeof b ? b : a, this.each(function() {
        this.setSelectionRange ? this.setSelectionRange(a, b) : this.createTextRange && (c = this.createTextRange(), c.collapse(!0), c.moveEnd("character", b), c.moveStart("character", a), c.select())
      })) : (this[0].setSelectionRange ? (a = this[0].selectionStart, b = this[0].selectionEnd) : document.selection && document.selection.createRange && (c = document.selection.createRange(), a = 0 - c.duplicate().moveStart("character", -1e5), b = a + c.text.length), {
        begin: a,
        end: b
      })
    },
    unmask: function() {
      return this.trigger("unmask")
    },
    mask: function(c, g) {
      var h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o;
      if (!c && this.length > 0) {
        h = a(this[0]);
        var p = h.data(a.mask.dataName);
        return p ? p() : void 0
      }
      return g = a.extend({
        autoclear: a.mask.autoclear,
        placeholder: a.mask.placeholder,
        completed: null
      }, g), i = a.mask.definitions, j = [], k = n = c.length, l = null, a.each(c.split(""), function(a, b) {
        "?" == b ? (n--, k = a) : i[b] ? (j.push(new RegExp(i[b])), null === l && (l = j.length - 1), k > a && (m = j.length - 1)) : j.push(null)
      }), this.trigger("unmask").each(function() {
        function h() {
          if (g.completed) {
            for (var a = l; m >= a; a++)
              if (j[a] && C[a] === p(a)) return;
            g.completed.call(B)
          }
        }

        function p(a) {
          return g.placeholder.charAt(a < g.placeholder.length ? a : 0)
        }

        function q(a) {
          for (; ++a < n && !j[a];);
          return a
        }

        function r(a) {
          for (; --a >= 0 && !j[a];);
          return a
        }

        function s(a, b) {
          var c, d;
          if (!(0 > a)) {
            for (c = a, d = q(b); n > c; c++)
              if (j[c]) {
                if (!(n > d && j[c].test(C[d]))) break;
                C[c] = C[d], C[d] = p(d), d = q(d)
              }
            z(), B.caret(Math.max(l, a))
          }
        }

        function t(a) {
          var b, c, d, e;
          for (b = a, c = p(a); n > b; b++)
            if (j[b]) {
              if (d = q(b), e = C[b], C[b] = c, !(n > d && j[d].test(e))) break;
              c = e
            }
        }

        function u() {
          var a = B.val(),
            b = B.caret();
          if (o && o.length && o.length > a.length) {
            for (A(!0); b.begin > 0 && !j[b.begin - 1];) b.begin--;
            if (0 === b.begin)
              for (; b.begin < l && !j[b.begin];) b.begin++;
            B.caret(b.begin, b.begin)
          } else {
            for (A(!0); b.begin < n && !j[b.begin];) b.begin++;
            B.caret(b.begin, b.begin)
          }
          h()
        }

        function v() {
          A(), B.val() != E && B.change()
        }

        function w(a) {
          if (!B.prop("readonly")) {
            var b, c, e, f = a.which || a.keyCode;
            o = B.val(), 8 === f || 46 === f || d && 127 === f ? (b = B.caret(), c = b.begin, e = b.end, e - c === 0 && (c = 46 !== f ? r(c) : e = q(c - 1), e = 46 === f ? q(e) : e), y(c, e), s(c, e - 1), a.preventDefault()) : 13 === f ? v.call(this, a) : 27 === f && (B.val(E), B.caret(0, A()), a.preventDefault())
          }
        }

        function x(b) {
          if (!B.prop("readonly")) {
            var c, d, e, g = b.which || b.keyCode,
              i = B.caret();
            if (!(b.ctrlKey || b.altKey || b.metaKey || 32 > g) && g && 13 !== g) {
              if (i.end - i.begin !== 0 && (y(i.begin, i.end), s(i.begin, i.end - 1)), c = q(i.begin - 1), n > c && (d = String.fromCharCode(g), j[c].test(d))) {
                if (t(c), C[c] = d, z(), e = q(c), f) {
                  var k = function() {
                    a.proxy(a.fn.caret, B, e)()
                  };
                  setTimeout(k, 0)
                } else B.caret(e);
                i.begin <= m && h()
              }
              b.preventDefault()
            }
          }
        }

        function y(a, b) {
          var c;
          for (c = a; b > c && n > c; c++) j[c] && (C[c] = p(c))
        }

        function z() {
          B.val(C.join(""))
        }

        function A(a) {
          var b, c, d, e = B.val(),
            f = -1;
          for (b = 0, d = 0; n > b; b++)
            if (j[b]) {
              for (C[b] = p(b); d++ < e.length;)
                if (c = e.charAt(d - 1), j[b].test(c)) {
                  C[b] = c, f = b;
                  break
                }
              if (d > e.length) {
                y(b + 1, n);
                break
              }
            } else C[b] === e.charAt(d) && d++, k > b && (f = b);
          return a ? z() : k > f + 1 ? g.autoclear || C.join("") === D ? (B.val() && B.val(""), y(0, n)) : z() : (z(), B.val(B.val().substring(0, f + 1))), k ? b : l
        }
        var B = a(this),
          C = a.map(c.split(""), function(a, b) {
            return "?" != a ? i[a] ? p(b) : a : void 0
          }),
          D = C.join(""),
          E = B.val();
        B.data(a.mask.dataName, function() {
          return a.map(C, function(a, b) {
            return j[b] && a != p(b) ? a : null
          }).join("")
        }), B.one("unmask", function() {
          B.off(".mask").removeData(a.mask.dataName)
        }).on("focus.mask", function() {
          if (!B.prop("readonly")) {
            clearTimeout(b);
            var a;
            E = B.val(), a = A(), b = setTimeout(function() {
              B.get(0) === document.activeElement && (z(), a == c.replace("?", "").length ? B.caret(0, a) : B.caret(a))
            }, 10)
          }
        }).on("blur.mask", v).on("keydown.mask", w).on("keypress.mask", x).on("input.mask paste.mask", function() {
          B.prop("readonly") || setTimeout(function() {
            var a = A(!0);
            B.caret(a), h()
          }, 0)
        }), e && f && B.off("input.mask").on("input.mask", u), A()
      })
    }
  })
});

$(function() {
  //2. Получить элемент, к которому необходимо добавить маску
  $("#xfield\\[tel\\]").mask("8(999) 999-9999");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="xfield" id="xfield[tel]" value="">
```

Comment: вообще идеологически это неправильный id,  никто так не пишет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишите код вот так:

```
$("#xfield\\[test\\]").mask("8(999) 999-9999");
```

То есть своего рода экранирование надо применять

Comment: Так-то всё работает. Но мне нужно его в php поставить, а там почему-то вырезаются двойные слэши и получается вот так `$("#xfield\[test\]")`, но так не работает. Что может их вырезать?

Comment: Без понятия......я не экстрасенс

Comment: там код большой, не как не показать

Comment: И что вы от меня хотите? Ставьте четыре обратных слэша в таком случае.

Comment: Вы гений !!!!!!!